# fullcalendar eventConstraint not working

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar and i came  to a situation that i want to restrict the events from dragging out side a date range,so i use eventconstraint but unfortunately its not working for me please correct me if there is any mistake in my code .I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59RCB/78/) with my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventConstraint:{    
                            start: '2015-02-01T10:00:00',
                            end: '2015-02-15T22:00:00'
                        },
        events: [
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'event',
                start: new Date(2015, 1, 4)
            },
        ],
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is using fullcalendar 1.6.1

The current version is 2.2.6.

[`eventConstraint`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventConstraint/) was *just* added in 2.2.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/59RCB/79/) that works (you also need momentjs for FC 2.0+).

CDN scripts:

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js`
`http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.6/fullcalendar.min.js`
`http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.6/fullcalendar.min.css`

Always load moment before fullcalendar.